Is it possible to remove keycode import in videojs8?
For security request, my project has been scanned by Sonatype Nexus Lifecycle. Which comes out with two issues by keycode:

So, may I ask is it possible to remove keycode in videojs8?
If yes, may I ask how can I remove then?

Yes, it's possible to remove the KeyCode. Try this:
const player = videojs('my-video');

player.on('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.which === 32) { // 32 for Space key
    // Handle space key press
  } else if (event.which === 13) { // 13 for Enter key
    // Handle enter key press
  }
});

In here, keydown event provided by Video.js to listen for key presses.
You can also check this: How to listen on keydown event in video tag?

I'm wonder is there any way to remove keycode which imported by default?
How can i remove import and will it affect the function of videojs8?
